# Is there a lib to convert timestamp into time offset

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a javascript library that takes unix timestamp string as an input and converts it to something like '5 minutes ago', '3 days ago', etc...

The purpose is to display time difference of the forum post but I don't want to apply this logic in the php script on the server, I want to send the data just how it's stored in database and let the client do this extra work.

Does anybody know if class of function exists in any js library for this?

Comment: Can I see who voted -1 for this question so I can return the favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://webdesign.onyou.ch/2010/08/04/javascript-time-ago-pretty-date/

and the mandatory jQuery plugin:

http://timeago.yarp.com/

Comment: Very good. jQuery plugin looks nice, now I have to figure out how to use it without jQuery because I use YUI and don't want to load jQuery too

Comment: My jQuery references are for karma whoring. YUI ROCKS :)

Answer (score 0):

Isnt is too trivial for "library"? Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/xszSg/

Comment: It's not too hard but you need to apply all the formatting like adding 's' to plural values, showing 'minutes ago' if less than an hour ago,